# Bash outputs command not found on Docker when evaluating two expressions

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I don't get why the below layer doesn't work:

```
RUN if [ "$PROMOTE" = 1 ] && [ "${MY_ENV}" = "PRODUCTION" ]; then curl -S -w "%{http_code}" -X GET "${API_URL}" |bash ; fi
```

It calls the URL inside `${API_URL}` variable, but bash aborts the build with the desired response from my api alongside with a "command not found" message.

```
bash: line 1: message:Your API has been called with status Approved200: command not found
```

My guess is the the problem lies in how I evaluate the above condition. Somehow bash does not accept it. This doesn't happens if I evaluate a single condition like e.g.:

```
RUN if [ "$PROMOTE" = 1 ]; then curl -S -w "%{http_code}" -X GET "${API_URL}" |bash ; fi
```

Comment: It appears that the document being returned by `curl` has the content `message:Your API has been called with status Approved` which has the `http_code` `200` concatenated onto the end of it. That is not valid `bash` syntax.

Comment: @WarzauWynn I tried removing the -w %{http_code} flag. So, now it returns only the api response. But still it comes with a "command not found" and breaks the build. I use the eaxct same format but for evaluating only a singlecondition and it wrks. I don't get it.

Comment: I could simply let go of bash, but that means I wouldn't have the outputs printed during build time. So, other people migh have no clue what is happening during the build.

Comment: `| bash` implies that what you expect to get from curl is a shell script. are you fetching a shell script?

Comment: @WarzauWynn not really. Is there any other way of outputing the curl response during build time, without this | bash atribute?

Comment: Yes. `curl -fsS -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n" -X GET "${API_URL}"`